# Track Changes in subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to track changes made to a subform. Anything added, deleted, or edited will be recorded in a table called Audit_tbl. When I make a add or edit a record I get this error:

> 3001: Invalid argument error.

I'm calling the function in the form as Before Update event procedure.

Attached are the reference libraries I've added.
[image]

```
Public Function AuditChanges(RecordID As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo auditerr

Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim clt As Control
Dim userloging As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select *from audit_tbl", adopendynamic)

UserLogin = Environ("Username")
Select Case UserAction
    Case "new"
        With rst
            .AddNew
            !\[DateTime\] = Now()
            !\[UserName\] = UserLogin
            !\[FormName\] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
            !\[Action\] = UserAction
            !\[RecordID\] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
            .Update

        End With

    Case "Delete"
        With rst
            .AddNew
            !\[DateTime\] = Now()
            !\[UserName\] = UserLogin
            !\[FormName\] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
            !\[Action\] = UserAction
            !\[RecordID\] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
            .Update
         End With

    Case "edit"
        For Each clt In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox) _
                Or (clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then
                If Nz(clt.Value) <> Nz(clt.OldValue) Then
                    With rst
                        .AddNew
                        !\[DateTime\] = Now()
                        !\[UserName\] = UserLogin
                        !\[FormName\] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                        !\[Action\] = UserAction
                        !\[RecordID\] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
                        !\[FieldName\] = clt.ControlSource
                        !\[OldValue\] = clt.Value
                        .Update
                    End With
                End If
          End If
    Next clt
End Select
rst.Close
db.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

auditerr:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Comment out the error handler - where is the error occurring?  I've never see that `!\[Name\]` pattern before so I assume that's some weird Access thing?

Comment: Crap, the !\[Name\] is a pasting error.  My bad, please ignore the \.  Vba is not highlighting any code.  I'm only getting the error message.

Comment: Check your error handling options in the VBA editor - you want "break in class module"

Comment: I've tried changing the "break in class module" and I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: But no specific line is highlighted when it breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.OpenRecordset` is DAO. `adOpenDynamic` is ADO. You can't combine them.

Use `dbOpenDynaset` instead to open a dynamic-type recordset.

Comment: I got it work run without any errors when I added ms activeX data objects recordset.... library to the reference.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really what you should do, while it does work by chance... You should've just replaced `adOpenDynamic` with `dbOpenDynaset`...